# Opening a text file for use in spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to be able to use text from a text file in my document, but no matter what I try python will not recognise the text file when I call it.

I need to write lines of code working out word count of a text file, the average of the numbers on each line and various other things.
To do this and run the code I need to use a text file I have created, which I called test.txt .
However when I run the code with `filename` set to test.txt (and other variations of this I tried), it tells me `NameError: name 'text' is not defined`

Below is an example of the lines I wrote for Word Count

```
def wc(filename):
    f = open('filename', 'r')
    w = f.split()
    return len(w)
```

If I call `a = 'ab c de fgh'` and do `wc(a)`
I get the correct answer 4
Now I need to do the same thing but have `'a'` coming from the text file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `'filename'` and `filename` are very different beasts. Also, your code doesn't mention the name `text` anywhere, so it can't produce the error you're talking about. Please post the actual code you're running

Comment: The point was even if I did open(text.txt, 'r') I can't get python to recognise my file as an existing text file.

If I input into the console wc(text.txt) it fails at the first step, being unable to find the text file.

it may be worth adding I've tried with and without the ' ' around filename.

Comment: Again, `text.txt` and `'text.txt'` are _very_ different.

Comment: Can you elaborate? 
Essentially what I need to know is how to properly open a text file in python, once I've managed that I should be able to do the rest.

Comment: Basically, `open` expects its first argument to be a _string_, like `'some/kind/of/file/path.thing'`, but you're typing in `text.txt`, which attempts to retrieve an attribute called `txt` of a variable `text`.

Comment: C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Python Scripts/text.txt
That was another method I tried, by typing in the entire directory. I also tried it with // instead of / just in case.

Comment: You're forgetting the _quotes_ around the path. It should be `"C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Python Scripts/text.txt"` (note the _quotes_)

Comment: Okay so now I believe it recognises the document by typing
    wc("C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Python Scripts/test.txt")
into the console, at least I'm not getting the error message for no 'text' file found. Now I have an error from the line 
w = f.split()
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: a different error means progress! (At least in this case). Now you're trying to `split` a file object. This doesn't make sense because file objects don't contain the file's data, so there's nothing to split. These objects do, however, provide ways of retrieving this data. You're looking for `def thing(filename): return len(open(filename).read().split())`. `read()` reads the whole content of the file and returns it as a string. Now, splitting strings does make sense, so here you go!

Comment: Okay I didn't quite do what your code did, instead I adapted mine to:
def wc(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    f = str(f)
    w = f.split()
    return len(w)
and I got a sensible value as a return!
Thank you so much, I've got coding labs tomorrow for Uni (Aerospace) and this is basically the first code I've ever written.
Is there a way to updoot/credit a good response?

Comment: Unfortunately, you got a "sensible" value that actually is meaningless in this context. Try to insert `print(f)` after `f = str(f)` to see why. To retrieve the contents of a file, use the `read` method, as shown above

Comment: So it's coincidence that the value returned and the value of the word count are both 5?

Comment: Well, edit your file to contain more words and see if it was a coincidence. `str(f)` will stringify the _file object_, which, as explained above, does not contain the data in the file. Yet it does provide methods of retrieving that data.

Comment: so when f = open(filename, 'r') it isn't reading it either?
Edit: So I re-did the code to what you said and predictably it worked, properly this time.
Just to clarify things for me, when I do open(filename) it opens the file I describe, appending it with .read returns the whole of the file back as a string, and then appending that with .split() separates it into a list about the white spaces. Prefixing all of that with len() returns the length of the index of that list.

Comment: Imagine if your file was 80GB of data and `open(that_file)` read these 80GB into your computer's memory. You'd immediately run out of memory! Instead, `open(...)` provides ways of reading _chunks of that data_, so one can read the whole content, or at most `N` bytes, or several lines. Please read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: When you say open(. . .) you mean the open followed by the . read followed by the .split?

Comment: Regarding the edit to your comment: yes, exactly. Well, you could be more precise about "appending" and "prefixing" stuff with other stuff: you're actually _calling functions_. Say, `open(...).read()` constructs the file object and then calls its `read` method. `len(...)` calls the built-in function named `len`.

Comment: Okay, my only question is that I don't quite get what you mean by the difference between open(that_file) and open(...).
What does the ... signify?

Comment: That's the same thing. I'm using [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) `...` instead of the actual arguments in the code to shorten it. BTW, [ellipsis `...` is valid Python](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#the-ellipsis-object), but that's not terribly relevant in this case

Comment: Oh Okay, I think I read too much into it.
Thank you so much for your help, not only did you help me get that section done, but I think it should help for the next part where I need to split a document into a list by each line of the document, and then return the average of each line.

Also your code showed me how it's possible to shorten down length functions. I've been essentially doing 1 function each line up until now, for example 
a = open(filename)
a = read(a)  
or something like that, not sure if that works tbh.

Comment: `a = read(a)` won't work. You're looking for `a = a.read()`. You should [read a Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) before attempting to write any code.

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant, I've used the same form earlier.
I'm just not used to it yet, so I need references fairly often.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to evaluate

```
    w = f.split()
```

to obtain words from a file object `f`.

What you want is

```
    w = f.read().split()
```

so you are splitting a string that came from `f`.

EDIT

You wrote

> AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split' is the error I am now getting returned.

I don't understand your remark.
I put the first two paragraphs of your question into a text file.
I ran this program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python


def wc(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    w = f.read().split()
    return len(w)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fspec = input('Count words in which file? ')
    print(wc(fspec))
```

Running that, plus `wc`, produces the following results:

```
108
       3     108     525
```

Looks like a little more than a hundred words, to me.

I wrote `.read().split()`, which is different from `.read.split()`.
Are you *sure* you called the `read` function?
Using `(` `)` parentheses makes a difference
in how the expression will be evaluated.

Comment: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split' is the error I am now getting returned.